# MS Word runs on background and requests documents to be saved even though it is already saved

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, office-interop, winforms-interop

I have a procedure that creates a PDF file according to an ms word template and its data is retrieved from a database.

It works fine, creates a PDF file perfectly , no run time errors. The problem is that whenever I shut off the computer, ms word prevents the shutdown and if I press cancel ms word shows a message;

[image]

The code goes like this;

```
   Dim wordApp As Word.Application
   Dim templateBookmarks As Word.Bookmarks
   Dim templateName As String
   Dim template As Word.Document
   'Some other variables for computations

   wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   sourceTable = New DataTable
   'Some other procs to fill the data table

   templateName = "Foo Template.docx" 
   template = wordApp.Documents.Add(templatePath & templateName)
   templateBookmarks = template.Bookmarks
   templateBookmarks.Item("sample bookmark").Range.Text = "foo"

   'Then fills the table in the template like...
   template.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = dataSource.Rows(0).Item(0)

  'Then saves the document as a pdf
  Dim saveName As String = "sample file"
  template.SaveAs2(savePath & saveName, Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF)
```

I have tried to force garbage collection for the word COM resources, as well as changing the template from an actual document i.e. docx to a word template .dotx. I also tried the method Quit() but it only shows the ms word message much earlier. This is the first time I needed to use interop so pardon if I don't have much idea about it.

The files I needed are saved, the only problem is the ms word message and unsaved and unnecessary files e.g. Document1,Document2,Document3 that seems to be created aside from the required PDF

Comment: Where are you closing the Word App in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Document.Close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.Document.Close(method)) method which closes the specified document after saving files using the PDF file format. It allows specifying the `SaveChanges` parameter which specifies the save action for the document. Can be one of the following `WdSaveOptions` constants: `wdDoNotSaveChanges`, `wdPromptToSaveChanges`, or `wdSaveChanges`.

```
On Error GoTo errorHandler 

ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

errorHandler: 
If Err = 4198 Then MsgBox "Document was not closed"
```

Comment: This solved the problem, thank you! In addition, I added back wordApp.quit() as commented by Andrew Mortimer